# Catch-22 when trying to delete a custom domain name from Azure

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am trying to delete a custom domain name, example.com, from my Azure directory, but getting an error about not being able to do so, when signed in as user that has 'example.com' in the user name. But if I try to create a new user, I get an error unless the username ends with @mycompanyname.com.

So how can I ever create a user that does not include 'example.com' in the user name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: I was allowed to create a user with `@usernamemycompanyname.onmicrosoft.com` as the domain name. That user doesn't have `mycompanyname.com` as part of the username.

I guess this is pretty obvious once you realize that the special `onmicrosoft.com` subdomain is created for you by default. I would have liked get a reminder about that in the error message or next the input field where you create new users.

(I still can't delete the domain name, though. Now I get an `ObjectPendingTakeover` error. I have created [another question to solve that issue](https://serverfault.com/q/943795/12024).)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the domain in question is set as the default domain. If so, you'll need to set another domain as the default. If you have no other custom domain to set as the default then you can set the onmicrosoft.com domain as the default.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. And yes, the domain was actually the default to domain to start with, but fortunately that was easy to change back to `usernameexample.onmicrosoft.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting domain is not as easy as it looks.

As you have figured out you should not be logon with a user that is part of that domain
As @joewerty mentioned the domain must not be the default domain
Bottom line, domain shouldn't be in use, nothing should lock the domain.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/domains-manage#delete-a-custom-domain-name

Hope this helps with this question and the other question.