# ObjectPendingTakeover error when deleting a custom domain name from Azure Active Directory

Tags: entra-id

I want to delete my custom domain name from Azure. The domain name is not the primary, I sign in with a user that does not have the domain name as part of the username and Azure writes that *"all checks have passed. Proceed to delete the domain"*. But when I click the delete button I get the error *"Unable to delete domain name"*. The details are listed below.

I have deleted all resources all users but one, and that final user does not have the domain name as part of the username.

I have also tried deleting the domain using the [forceDelete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/domain-forcedelete?view=graph-rest-beta) method of the Graph API. That also returns an ObjectPendingTakeover error. For those interested I followed [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/21/using-postman-to-call-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-client-credentials/), replacing the `Resource` parameter with `scope` set to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` to get the access token for version 2.0/beta of the API.

Any suggestions as to what I could try?

```
{
    "errorCode": "ObjectPendingTakeover",
    "localizedErrorDetails": {
        "errorDetail": "Domain deletion attempt failed."
    },
    "operationResults": null,
    "timeStampUtc": "2018-12-11T07:44:21.4283076Z",
    "clientRequestId": "a631...",
    "internalTransactionId": "f899...",
    "upn": "adm...",
    "tenantId": "7176...",
    "userObjectId": null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete the domain name by navigation to https://aad.portal.azure.com/. This is focused version the Azure portal, where you only have access to the Azure Active Directory tab, so I would not have bet on this site behaving any differently that the full portal, but lo and behold here I was finally able to the domain! \o/

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this in the Azure portal by following this way:

1. Sign into the Azure portal using an account with global admin privileges for that directory.
2. Open your directory, and select **custom domains name**.
3. Select the domain and click Delete

For the details, you could read [here](https://github.com/toddkitta/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-add-domain-delete-domain.md).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @SunnySun, and thanks for the link. These are unfortunately already the exact steps that I am taking. :-(